# Plugins for eclipse providing the functionalities in Source Insight

Tags: eclipse, plugins

[Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com) is one great program editing system that has features finetuned for developers. The one IDE that comes close to what Source Insight provides is Eclipse, however I miss features like Relation Window, Browse Project Symbols etc. Are there any plugins to fill those gaps?

Comment: I take it you've already tried http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't seen anything close to what Source Insight is. thanks Dave

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: I think you'd have to explain what those things are, not simply name them, for anyone to give you ideas.